# Deleting bulk users with First name and last name

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I want to make a script that deletes bulk users, instead of using `SAMACCOUNTNAME` I want to use the first and last name, is that possible?

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$ADusers = Import-csv C:\TEST\Delete.CSV

Foreach ($user in $ADusers) {
    #Confirming the identity
    $users = Get-ADUser -Identity $user -Properties | Select-Object Givenname, Surename 

    #Removing the user       
    Remove-ADUser -Identity  $user.samAccountName -Confirm:$false
 }
```

Comment: SAMAccoutName is unique to a single account, but you can have multiple users with the same First/Last name. Have you thought about this situation?

Comment: Yes i thought about that, i wanted to use UPN but i couldn't found anything about that

Answer (score 1):

I like [Ambiguous Name Resolution](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22653.active-directory-ambiguous-name-resolution.aspx) when searching for users in AD:

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(anr=Jim Smith)"
```

This will search for all objects where any of the naming attributes (see link above for list) start with the string `"jim smith"`, plus all objects where `(givenName=jim*)` and `(sn=smith*)`, plus objects where `(givenName=smith*)` and `(sn=jim*)`.

This is useful when 'Jims' account uses his fully name of 'Jimmy', this would be returned by ANR but not by a direct `givenName`/`sn` filter.

You can have multiple users with the same First/Last name, so you will need to deal with the situation of multiple users being returned.

`SAMAccoutName`, however is unique to a single account

---

EDIT:

If you've got a csv with the two columns GivenName & Surname:

```
foreach ($user in $ADusers) {            
    $firstname = $user.GivenName
    $lastname = $user.Surname

    Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(anr=$firstname $lastname)"
}
```

The above just lists the users returned from `Get-ADUser`, to remove them just pipe to `Remove-ADUser`. I'm using `WhatIf` to test, remove to actually delete the users:

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(anr=$firstname $lastname)" | Remove-ADUser -WhatIf
```

Comment: what do i need to do when i want to use this with an CSV file?

Comment: What do u recommend/what is your advice and how do i add the command line remove-aduser?

Comment: #Activeert import module
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# Import of the csv file
$ADusers = Import-csv C:\TEST\Delete.CSV

#Confirming the identity
$foreach ($user in $ADusers)           
 {   $firstname = $user.GivenName
    $lastname = $user.Surname

    Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(anr=$firstname $lastname)"

 
 #Removing the user       
 Remove-ADUser -Identity  $user.firstname "+" lastname -Confirm:$false
} what did i do wrong

Comment: It's still not working: #Activeert import module Import-Module ActiveDirectory # Import of the csv file $ADusers = Import-csv C:\TEST\Delete.CSV #Confirming the identity $foreach ($user in $ADusers) { $firstname = $user.GivenName $lastname = $user.Surname Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(anr=$firstname $lastname)" | Remove-ADUser -WhatIf }

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {GivenName -eq "Max" -and sn -eq "Muller"} | Remove-ADUser
```

You need to alter your script accordingly.

Comment: I'm getting a fault, the fault say: ünexpected token get-aduser in expression or statement